# Ошибка валидатора (он не работает) "unique" в Yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

У меня есть валидация:

```
public function rules()
{
    return  [
    [
        ['login','email','password_1','password_2'],'required','message' => 'Это поле не может быть пустым.'],
        ['email','email','message' => 'Электронная почта не является действительным адресом электронной почты.'],
        ['email','unique','targetAttribute' => 'email','targetClass' => 'app\models\User','message' =>  'Такой логин уже зарегистрирован'],

];
}
```

Есть и поле в виде

```
<?= $form->field($model,'email')->textInput() ?>
```

Есть клас ActiveRecord(User)
Есть таблица в безе с таким полем

Чего оно не работает?

Answer (score 1):

Замените:

```
['email','unique','targetAttribute' => 'email','targetClass' => 'app\models\User','message' =>  'Такой логин уже зарегистрирован'],
```

на

```
['email', 'exist', 'targetAttribute' => 'email', 'targetClass' => User::className(), 'message' =>  'Такой логин уже зарегистрирован'],
```

Comment: Не сработало, спасибо я уже сделал вручную валидацию